# Laravel + Mongodb full text search

Tags: mongodb, laravel

How do I make mongodb text search work in Laravel? Please suggest.

I can do that on terminal -

```
db.coupons.find( { $text: { $search: "Search me here" } } )
```

But not sure how to do it in laravel.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To search using laravel mongodb (with jenssegers/laravel-mongodb) you need to create an index first. Ex: `db.articles.createIndex( { "subject" : "text" } )`, where `subject` is the text attribute to make the search.

Then you can try a query in mongodb: `db.articles.find( { $text: { $search: "coffee" } } )` or do it in Laravel:

```
$word = "coffee";
$response = Article::whereRaw(array('$text'=>array('$search'=> $word)))->get();
```

If you want to search by a phrase you need tu use the quotes. In mongodb: `db.articles.find( { $text: { $search: "\"coffee shop\"" } } )` and Laravel:

```
$word = "coffee shop";
$response = Article::whereRaw(array('$text'=>array('$search'=> "\"" . $word . "\"")))->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Add [jenssegers/laravel-mongodb](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb) package in your composer.json and install that through `composer update`. Visit added link, there you will get good source to deal with mongodb-laravel connection.

Have you tried something like:

```
$users = User::with(array('posts' => function($query)
{
    $query->where('title', 'like', '%first%');

}))->get();
```

See if that helps.

Comment: I'm already using it. But not sure how to use full text search.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb, according to your code you can do say

$coupons= Coupons::where('$text' =>['$search' =>'Search me here' ]);

}))->get();